# django.test.TestCase AtrributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, python-3.x

I get the above error when attempting to run unit tests while following [this](http://www.marinamele.com/taskbuster-django-tutorial/create-home-page-with-tdd-staticfiles-templates-settings) tutorial.

The class which contains the unit tests is as follows :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.test import TestCase
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse


class TestHomePage(TestCase):

    def test_uses_index_template(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("home"))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "taskbuster/index.html")

    def test_uses_base_template(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("home"))
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "base.html")
```

It throws the error when calling `self.client.get()` method.

Help would be appreciated.

The traceback that is thrown :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bIgB/Programming/languages/python/taskbuster_project /taskbuster/test.py", line 9, in test_uses_index_template
response = self.client.get(reverse("home"))
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 500, in get
**extra)
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 303, in get
return self.generic('GET', path, secure=secure, **r)
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 379, in generic
return self.request(**r)
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 466, in request
six.reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 659, in reraise
raise value
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 223, in get_response
response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/Users/bIgB/.virtualenvs/tb_test/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django/middleware/clickjacking.py", line 31, in process_response
if response.get('X-Frame-Options', None) is not None:
```

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Please add the full error traceback. If you can't see it, run `manage.py test` with the arguments `-v 3 --traceback`.

Comment: You should also show the code of your home view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman The home view only contains the `home` method which returns the empty string. Following the tutorial, it hasn't reached a point yet where the appropriate template is returned by the view.

Comment: But "returning the empty string" is precisely the problem, because views must always return an HttpResponse, whether or not they are using a template.